# Only draw when one string does not equal the other?

Tags: processing

I have a text file that I'm continuously checking the last line to see if it's changed. I only want Processing to update the drawing when the last line of the file has changed, but I can't think of how to do it.

This is what I have so far, where lastLine checks the last line of the file:

```
String last = lastLine(file);
String previous = null;

float r = random(0,255);
float g = random(0, 255);
float b = random(0, 255);



    public void settings() {
        size(500, 500);
    }
    public void setup() {
      frameRate(60);
        stroke(155, 0, 0);
        textSize(30);
    }

    void draw() {
      if (last != previous) {
          background(r+(random(0,100)), g+(random(0,100)), b+(random(0,100)));
          previous = last;
      }

      if (last == previous) {
        text(lastLine(file), 255, 255);
      }
    }
```

Right now this updates the text as the file changes, but the background remains the same.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When comparing `String` values, don't use the `==` operator. Use the `equals()` method:

```
if (last.equals(previous)) {
```

To check that they're **not** equal, use the `!` operator:

```
if (!last.equals(previous)) {
```

From [the reference](https://www.processing.org/reference/String.html):

> To compare the contents of two Strings, use the equals() method, as in if (a.equals(b)), instead of if (a == b). A String is an Object, so comparing them with the == operator only compares whether both Strings are stored in the same memory location. Using the equals() method will ensure that the actual contents are compared. (The [troubleshooting reference](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Troubleshooting#Why_don.27t_these_Strings_equal.3F) has a longer explanation.)